# Heap usage is less but free memory is less

Tags: linux, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I have 10 gb RAM

Application max heap : 8 GB

current app heap usage: 3 GB

Free memory : 188mb

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9993        9362         188           2         442         326
Swap:          4095         866        3229
```

So if we assign Xmx to 8GB . will the RAM reserve the 8gb for application heap ?

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will reserve 8GB in its virtual address space for Java Heap.
Note there are other memory areas used for Thread stacks, GC, JIT Code cache, Direct Buffers, etc., so your Java process may consume more than just `-Xmx` amount of memory.

I'm not sure what you're getting to when saying "Heap usage is less but free memory is less" but if you're wondering why the free part of memory isn't ~2 GB or even ~7 GB,
then this might be because:

- JVM needs more memory than just heap (as mentioned before),
- what you report as "current app heap usage" may be misleading and GCs often don't return unused memory to OS (you may want to look at "total memory" usage)
- OS itself and other applications need some memory too